# Access 2010 - Enter parameter value on report but not in query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010 and create a string filter on the fly by pulling information from the user via various controls on a subform.  I then use the filter in one of two ways:

- I set the recordsource of another subform in datasheet view

  ```
  Forms![frmCentral]![TrainingEventsSubform].Form.RecordSource =
  ```

  gstrTrainingEventsFormFilter
- Or I use it as the query parameter of openreport

  ```
      DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTrainingEvents", acViewPreview, gstrTrainingEventsFormFilter
  ```

I don't understand why, but the query string works fine when setting the recordsource, but the exact same string will result in an Enter Parameter Value box appearing when issuing the openreport command.  Further, the query works perfectly if I paste it into the report's recordsource parameter.

As an example, here's a string that's built:

```
SELECT TrainingEvents.StartDate, TrainingEvents.EndDate, ClassList.ClassNumber, [Users].[FirstName] & ' ' & [Users].[LastName] AS Trainer, TrainingLocations.TrainingLocationName, EventVenues.EventVenueName, TrainingEventStatus.TrainingEventStatus, TrainingEvents.TrainingEventID
FROM Users INNER JOIN (TrainingLocations INNER JOIN (TrainingEventStatus INNER JOIN (EventVenues INNER JOIN (ClassList INNER JOIN TrainingEvents ON ClassList.ClassID = TrainingEvents.ClassID) ON EventVenues.EventVenueID = TrainingEvents.EventVenueID) ON TrainingEventStatus.TrainingEventStatusID = TrainingEvents.EventStatusID) ON TrainingLocations.TrainingLocationID = TrainingEvents.TrainingLocationID) ON Users.UserID = TrainingEvents.TrainerID
WHERE (TrainingEvents.StartDate >= #1/1/2014#) AND (TrainingEvents.EndDate <= #12/31/2014#) AND (Users.UserID = 10)
ORDER BY TrainingEvents.StartDate;
```

The Enter Parameter Value box appears with Users.UserID.

It's obviously something with userid, but for the life of me I can't understand what!

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that UserID is used somewhere in your report, but it is not included in the select clause. Try including it.

Comment: I also had to change it in the report's recordsource

Comment: I don't understand why it worked for the form but not the report.  Seems inconsistent.  Although the bottom line is that the query string was constructed incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciate it.  Would have stared at it for hours and not figured it out.